# How to wait for all async REST calls are finished using Unirest?

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, unirest

Being new to async programming i am wondering how i van wait for all futures to complete?

In my current use case i have to read a file and post the content line by line using JSON post to a REST Webservice. But when i do this in the normal way the program exists before all Futures are finished.

Below is some code from the program.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Future<HttpResponse<String>> future = Unirest.post("http://www.dummy.net")
        .fields(map)
        .asStringAsync(new Callback<String>() {
            public void completed(HttpResponse<String> response) {
                int code = response.getStatus();
            }

            public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                System.out.println("The request has failed");
            }

            public void cancelled() {
                System.out.println("The request has been cancelled");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This code runs and exists before all Futures have been completed. Any hint on how i can wait for all Futures to complete?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Put all these Futures to collection, e.g. ArrayList. And get them all.

```
List<Future> futures = ...
// your while loop

    foreach(Future f : futures) f.get();
```